# Shift array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, shift

I need some help, I know this question was asked before but I don't get it and I cant solve it, so I need help. I need to move the elements of my array to a position to left. So if the input will be 1,2,3,4,5 then the output will be 2,3,4,5,1. I have done the same to right but to left I cant figure it out, please also explain the logic , thanks.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int a[100],n,i,tempr,templ;
    int main()
    {
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) cin >> a[i];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            tempr = a[n];
            a[n] = a[i];
            a[i] = tempr;
            cout<<"Right: "<<a[i]<<endl;
        }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            templ = a[2];
            a[2] = a[i];
            a[i] = templ;
            cout<<"Left: "<<a[i]<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/

Comment: the indexing is wrong, it looks like basic C code wrapped in C++.

Comment: thnks for the link but can you please help me make it go left like it works for right, I want to understand I that way please

Comment: The first element in an array is a[0] the last a[size-1]

Comment: `a[2]` is  the third element, not the second. Your indexing is off by one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First problem is bad indexing:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) cin >> a[i]; //wrong logic, C++ indexing start from 0
```

Correct approach:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) //all your loops
```

Second problem is wrong logic for shifting elements:
Corrected version:

```
//input example: 1 2 3 4 5
//to the left
int temp = a[0]; //remember first element
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    a[i] = a[i+1]; //move all element to the left except first one
}
a[n-1] = temp; //assign remembered value to last element
//output: 2 3 4 5 1
cout << "To left: " << endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout << a[i] << endl;

//to the right
temp = a[n-1]; //remember last element
for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    a[i+1] = a[i]; //move all element to the right except last one
}
a[0] = temp; //assign remembered value to first element
//output: 1 2 3 4 5 because elements are shifted back by right shift
cout << "To right: " << endl;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout << a[i] << endl;
```

---

EDIT:

How to display both shifts:

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int to_left[5], to_right[5],n,i,tempr,templ;
    int main()
    {

    cout << "Input array size: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> to_left[i]; //read values to first array
        to_right[i]=to_left[i]; //then copy values to second one
    }

    //shift first array to left
    int temp = to_left[0]; 
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        to_left[i] = to_left[i+1]; //move all element to the left except first one
    }
    to_left[n-1] = temp; //assign remembered value to last element
    //output: 2 3 4 5 1
    cout << "To left: " << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << to_left[i] << endl;

    //shift second array to right
    temp = to_right[n-1]; //remember last element
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        to_right[i+1] = to_right[i]; //move all element to the right except last one
    }
    to_right[0] = temp; //assign remembered value to first element
    //output: 1 2 3 4 5 because elements are shifted back by right shift
    cout << "To right: " << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << to_right[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that your code look very much like C code. In C++, you can declare variables in any segment of code, not just at the beginning. In C++, you can declare variable in `for` loop like this: `for(int i=0; i<...)` - no need for global variable `i`

For reference, this would be good C++ code example that satisfies problem you are facing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{   
    std::size_t n; //size_t is unsiged type used for various sizes of containers or types
    std::cout << "Input array size: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> to_left(n), to_right(n); //two dynamic arrays containing integers, takin n as their size

    for(std::size_t i=0;i<to_left.size();++i) //use vector size(), instead of n, also ++i in considered better for loops that i++ (may be faster)
    {
        std::cin >> to_left[i];
        to_right[i]=to_left[i];
    }

    int temp = to_left[0]; //declare temp here, not at the begining of code
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<n-1;++i)
        to_left[i] = to_left[i+1];
    to_left[n-1] = temp;

    std::cout << "To left: " << std::endl;
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<n;++i)
        std::cout << to_left[i] << std::endl;

    temp = to_right[n-1]; //reuse temp
    for(int i=to_right.size()-1;i>=0;--i) //note int, not std::size_t, because size_t is always >=0, loop would never end.
        to_right[i+1] = to_right[i];
    to_right[0] = temp;

    std::cout << "To right: " << std::endl;
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
        std::cout << to_right[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here would be ideal C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{   
    std::size_t n;
    std::cout << "Input array size: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> to_left(n), to_right(n);

    for(std::size_t i=0;i<to_left.size();++i)
    {
        std::cin >> to_left[i];
        to_right[i]=to_left[i];
    }

    // rotate first array to the left
    std::rotate(to_left.begin(), to_left.begin() + 1, to_left.end());

    // rotate second array to right
    std::rotate(to_right.rbegin(), to_right.rbegin() + 1, to_right.rend());

    std::cout << "To left:" << std::endl;
    for(auto x : to_left) //C++11 feature, x iterates through container
        std::cout << x << std::endl;

    std::cout << "To right:" << std::endl;
    for(auto x : to_right)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for everything, I have a question: for the part where you move to right, can you make it  like this

Comment: can I make it somehow turn to right the initial array not the left array but the initial so that the output will be 51234

Comment: You would need to make second array, move first array to the left, and second one to the right (or move first array two times to the right after moving it to left). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: to_right[i+1] will result in i+1 == n for the first iteration (your array last index + 1). Did you mean n - 2 or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use memmove(...) projected exactly for those purpose, here your sample:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std; 
//rotate Left
void r_left(int *a,int n) 
{ 
  int tmp=a[0];
  memmove(a,a+1,sizeof(int)*(n-1));
  a[n-1]=tmp;
} 
//rotate right
void r_right(int *a,int n) 
{ 
    int tmp=a[n-1];
    memmove(a+1,a,sizeof(int)*(n-1));
    a[0]=tmp;
 } 
void show(int *a,int n)
{
   while(n--)
   cout<<*a++<<' ';
   cout<<endl;
}

int main() 
{ 
   int ar[]={1,2,3,4,5};
   int n=sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
   r_left(ar,n);
   show(ar,n);
   r_right(ar,n);
   show(ar,n);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

easiest way to swap elements in C++ is to use std::iter_swap()

so for an array of 4 elements to swap elements 1 and 4 you would do the following

```
int a[4];
std::iter_swap(a, a+3);
```

note that you also need to `#include <algorithm>` for this to work

the basic logic of the function is that you give the location in memory of the 2 elements, so as the first element of an array is also its location in memory, you can pass a + n, when n is equal to the n-1 index number of the element you want to swap

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int a[100], outR[100], outL[100], n, i;
    int main() {
      cin >> n;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
      // Right
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        outR[i+1]= a[i];
      } 
      outR[0] = a[n-1]; // add first number
      // Left
      for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        outL[i-1]= a[i];
      }         
      outL[n-1] = a[0]; // add last number
      // Answer
      cout << "Right:\n";
      for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << outR[i] << endl;
        }
      cout << "Left:\n";
      for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << outL[i] << endl;
      }
        return 0;
    }
```

Simple answer where you can easily see everything, good luck.

You may be interested in ,,vector coding", it seems be easier if you spend some time on this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    vector <int> a, outR, outL;
    size_t i;
    int main () {
      int n, temp_int;
      cin >> n;
      while (n--) {
        cin >> temp_int;  // here you read number to your vector
        a.push_back(temp_int);  // here you add this to vector
        // remember that vector start from element 0 as like arrays
      }
      // Left
      // remember that last element will be first
      // you may have acces to size of your vector easily
      for (i = 0; i < (a.size()-1); i++) {
        outL.push_back(a.at(i+1));  // here you create new vector
      }
      outL.push_back(a.at(0)); // add last elemet which rotated

      // Right
      // to rotate left first you have push last element so
      outR.push_back(a.at(a.size()-1)); // add first elemet which rotated
      for (i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        outR.push_back(a.at(i-1));  // here you push rest
        }

      cout << "Left"  << "\n";
      for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << outL.at(i) << endl;  // here you print value  
      }
      cout << "Right" << "\n";
      for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        cout << outR.at(i) << endl;  // here you print value  
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As other already have stated it's all about indices. In a for-loop you are almost always in trouble if your stop condition is i <= size, because arrays in C++ are zero-indexed.

Where Black Moses alogrithm is far the easiest to understand (and probably the fastes), I read your code as if you try to swap the first value of the array through the array to the last position. Below I have tried to pin out this approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

void ShiftLeft(int* pArr, size_t length)
{
  for (size_t i = 1; i < length; i++)
  {
    int tmp = pArr[i - 1]; // Preserves the previous value
    pArr[i - 1] = pArr[i]; // Overwrites the previous position with the current value
    pArr[i] = tmp;         // Stores the previous value in the current position
                           // All in all the first value is swapped down the array until it is at the length - 1 position
                           // and all the other values are swapped to the left.

    /* For an array with 4 values the progression is as follows:
      i = 0: 1 2 3 4
      i = 1: 2 1 3 4
      i = 2: 2 3 1 4
      i = 3: 2 3 4 1    
    */

  }
}

void ShiftRight(int* pArr, size_t length)
{
  for (size_t i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    // This code does exactly the same as for ShiftLeft but the loop is running backwards
    int tmp = pArr[i - 1];
    pArr[i - 1] = pArr[i];
    pArr[i] = tmp;
  }
}

void Print(int* pArr, size_t length)
{

  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    std::cout << pArr[i] << " ";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  size_t length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

  Print(arr, length);
  ShiftLeft(arr, length);
  Print(arr, length);
  ShiftRight(arr, length);
  Print(arr, length);


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int*  leftShiftOneByOneWIthoutTemp(int arr[], int sz)
{

    for (int i=0 ;i < sz-1; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[sz-1] + arr[i];
        arr[sz-1] = arr[i] - arr[sz-1] ;
        arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[sz-1] ;
        std::cout << "iter  "<< i << std::endl;
        printArray(arr,5);

    }   
    std::cout << "final "<< std::endl;
    printArray(arr,5);

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: plz add some description to answer for help questioner

Answer (score -1):

> Replace your code (to shift array left) with below code.

```
templ = a[0];
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i+1];
        cout<<"Left: "<<a[i]<<endl;
    }
    a[n-1] = templ;
    cout<<"Left: "<<a[n-1]<<endl;
```

Comment: Would be useful if you explained what was wrong with the ops code, what you changed, and why.